# Rails 4 Update Active Record with JSON data from AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I've spent some time looking around but there does not seem to be an answer to this question. Any help appreciated.

I'm sending JSON data with an AJAX call back to my Rails app (no CORS).

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/tasks/",
        data: JSON.stringify(res),
        datatype: "json",
        async: true
       });
```

The JSON data (res) as copied from the browser console:

```
[{"task_id":"9","grid_position":[0,2,2,2,false]},{"task_id":"8","grid_position":[0,0,2,2,false]}]:
```

So far so good.

This then gets sent via the route:

```
resources :tasks,               only: [:index, :update, :create, :destroy]
```

to the Tasks Controller, where I am trying to reach the Update Action:

```
def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    respond_to :html, :json
    if @task.update_attributes(task_params)
       flash[:success] = "Task updated"
        redirect_to @user
    else
    flash[:error] = "Task not saved! Please see guidance by form labels"
        redirect_to user_url(current_user)
    end
end
```

I cannot access the Update action in the Tasks Controller. I have tried changing the URL, changing POST to PUT, and I'm stumped.

The server error message:

```
Started POST "/tasks" for 217.137.84.197 at 2015-08-19 15:25:25 +0000
Processing by TasksController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"{\"task_id\":\"9\",\"grid_position\":"=>{"0,2,2,2,false"=>{"},{\"task_id\":\"8\",\"grid_position\":"=>{"0,0,2,2,false"=>{"}"=>nil}}}}}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

I can understand that it's looking for Users as it is trying to create a new task, which must have a User ID. However, I am only wanting to update an existing task.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the params: def task_params
            params.require(:task).permit(:label, :address, :content, :grid_position)
         end

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST"
```

triggers the create action.

If you want to update a task, use

```
type: "PATCH"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me tangrufus. I have tried PATCH as well as PUT, should have put that in the original question. 'code' ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/tasks"): 'code'

Comment: Did you add task id to the path (url) ?

Comment: I was rather hoping that the tasks controller would be able to see the task ID in the JSON and find the appropriate record.

Comment: Then, you need a new route and a new controller method

Comment: However, I would suggest you to go with RESTful routes. Check this [post](http://www.redguava.com.au/2011/02/rails-basics-using-rails-routes-in-jquery-ajax-callbacks/) about adding task ids to urls

Answer (score 0):

I have worked this out but it took me a day so I thought I should post. Thanks to tangrufus for the helpful pointers.

Javascript(jquery)

```
  $.ajax({
       type: "PATCH",
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',//very important for rails it seems
       dataType: 'json',
       url: taskURL,
       data: JSON.stringify(task),
       cache: false,
       });
```

There is also a problem with JSON stringify, in that it will not take non-numeric values in an array. Problem for another day.

In the Tasks Controller

```
wrap_parameters format: [:json, :xml]
```

and also in params you need to make special allowance for an array in Rails 4 (who knew?)

```
def task_params
params.require(:task).permit(:id, :label, :address, :content, {:grid_position => []})
end
```